# C++ binary tree object, "insert" method with 1 parameter

Tags: c++, tree, binary

I'm learning binary trees and want to implement with OOP where I have a `struct Node` and create a BST Object. I'm trying to create an insert function with this approach and am running into the issue where I can't recursively traverse the tree to add a new node - that is, unless I overload the method, essentially copying it, to call the new method with a pointer to `left` or `right`. Hard to explain, but right now I have two methods, and I'm not sure if I'm missing something obvious to just have 1 method with 1 parameter `int data`, or if this approach just isn't correct. I feel like there's something valuable for me to learn here. Many thanks.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Node
{
    Node *right;
    Node *left;
    int data;
};

class BST
{
public:
    Node* root;

public:
    BST()
    :root(NULL)
    {
    }

    //inserts node taking parameter data
    Node* insertNode(int data)
    {
        //if tree is empty, create root
        if (root == NULL)
        {
            root = newNode(data);
        }
        //if data is smaller than or equal to root, insert left
        else if (data <= root->data)
        {
            root->left = insertNode(root->left, data);
        }
        //data is larger than root, insert right
        else
        {
            root->right = insertNode(root->right, data);
        }
        return root;
    }      

    //inserts new node
    Node* insertNode(Node *root, int data)
    {
        //if tree is empty, create root
        if (root == NULL)
        {
            root = newNode(data);
        }
        //if data is smaller than or equal to root, insert left
        else if (data <= root->data)
        {
            root->left = insertNode(root->left, data);
        }
        //data is larger than root, insert right
        else
        {
            root->right = insertNode(root->right, data);
        }
        return root;
    }

    Node* newNode(int data)
    {
        Node *temp = new Node;
        temp->data = data;
        temp->left = NULL;
        temp->right = NULL;
        return temp;
    }

};

int main() {

    BST bst1;
    bst1.insertNode(30);
    bst1.insertNode(15);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just wondering, did I break a rule or ask something particularly unintelligent? I've been down voted a lot so don't want to make the same mistakes in the future

Comment: I think this is a pretty decent question (has a verifiable example, explains the problem). You should probably add a clear question statement. It might also be that people dislike it when askers to do manual memory management, but how else would you learn why smart pointers are so good? As in, your should probably state somewhere "How can I avoid duplicating this code?".

Comment: A good suggestion! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the redundancy by having one call forward to the other:

```
Node* insertNode(int data)
{
    return insertNode(root, data);
}
```

Note that having identical names for your class member (`Node* root`) and the local variable in `Node* insertNode(Node *root, int data)` is error-prone.

Also please do not forget to `delete` what you `new`.

Comment: If I wanted to only have 1 method, would I have to change my implementation in some way? Not looking for you to solve it for me, but I'm just wondering if that taking this approach makes it impossible to do. So my question would be: with OOP is there a way to avoid copying functions?

Comment: Yeah there would be some changes needed because `root == null` means different things at different times in your code. Btw, I removed my statement that your current version is wrong in this aspect (if you make `insertNode(Node *root, int data)` private at least), sorry for that. It might still make sense to have two methods (one public that just takes `data`, creates a root node if missing and otherwise calls a private method that does the recursive search), as long as they do different things (i.e. don't duplicate code). Having the recursive search as its own (private) method might be good.

Comment: Thank you :) One comment on your answer, shouldn't the method be: `Node* insertNode(int data)
{
    root = insertNode(root, data); return root;
}` ?